# java for loop not working

Tags: java, syntax, for-loop, iteration

I hope this isn't a stupid question but I have looked up every example I can find and it still seems like I have this code right and it still isn't working... I enter one number and it moves on to the next line of code instead of looping. I'm using this to fill an array with user input numbers. I appreciate any help, thanks.

```
for(i=0; i<9; i++);
{  
    System.out.println ("Please enter a number:");  
    Num[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();  
    Sum += Num[i];      
    Product *= Num[i];      
}
```

Comment: This could should not even compile. The `i` is not declared. Unless you have `i` declared globally somewhere at the top.

Comment: By that rational, neither is `Num`, `keyboard`, `Sum`, or `Product`.

Comment: You should probably select an answer to your question.

Answer (score 17):

The `;` at the end of the for loop is taken as an empty statement, the equivalent of an empty block for your for-loop.  The compiler is reading your code as:

```
int i;
....
for(i=0; i<9; i++)
    /* no-op */;

/* inline block with no relation to for-loop */
{  
    System.out.println ("Please enter a number:");  
    Num[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();  
    Sum += Num[i];      
    Product *= Num[i];      
}
```

Remove the `;` to get your intended behavior.

---

If you don't need the `i` outside of the loop, you could move its declaration within the `for` statement.

```
for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
{
   // `i` is only usable here now
}
// `i` is now out of scope and not usable
```

Using this syntax when the erroneous semicolon `;` was present would have produced a compile error that would alerted you to the erroneous `;` earlier. THe compiler would see this:

```
for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    /* no-op */;

/* inline block with no relation to for-loop */
{  
    System.out.println ("Please enter a number:");  
    Num[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();     // compile error now - `i` is out-of-scope
    Sum += Num[i];      
    Product *= Num[i];      
}
```

This would be an example why it is good practice to limit the scope of variables when possible.

Comment: Wow I knew it was going to be something stupid... arrrrgh. Thanks so much though!! It's now working as intended :)

Answer (score 7):

Noticed the ';' at the end of for(i=0; i<9; i++);  ? ^_^

Answer (score 4):

remove the last character semicolon from for loop line ............

Answer (score 4):

To avoid this mistake in future you should always use a fresh variable in a for loop. Instead of:

```
for (i = 0; ...
```

write

```
for (int i = 0; ...
```

That way it would be a compile-time error, since the variable *i* would not be in scope in the following block.

Comment: Although I would recommend your tactic, I can't see how this would have avoid this mistake of Steve

Comment: in the code `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++); { i++; }` the identifier `i` goes out of scope after the semicolon and before the block.

Comment: It would have reduced the probability of the mistake, since i would be scoped to the for loop. Now Num[i] in the block below it works since i obviously has been defined before it, but otherwise a compile error would follow and the programmer would more easily realize the compound statement (the block) and the for loop are separated.

Answer (score 3):

There shouldn't be a semicolon at the end of the first line.  It indicates your loop is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The answer has already been given, but I'd like to add that if you are using an IDE*, there will probably be a warning for those kinds of empty statements and other easy to make, easy to overlook type of mistakes (assinging instead of comparing in conditions for example).

- *see for example page http://hubpages.com/hub/Java-Debugging-Tip-The-Empty-Statement on exactly this mistake and how NetBeans can help you spot it.*

Answer (score 0):

just to let you know. something like this:

```
for(;;)
  ;
```

should send your program into busy-waiting. happened to me in the early days. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove that semi-colon after the "for(....)"

```
for(i=0; i<9; i++); //<---------- over here
```

you don't have to put a semi-colon over here. Most probably you were aware of that, it happens.
Additional points:
The syntax for "for" is:

```
for(initializer; condition; change){
//code here
}
```

The syntax for "while" is:

```
while(condition without semi-colon){
//code here
}
```

The syntax for "do-while" is:

```
do{
//code here
}while(condition);//<---------------semi-colon here.
```

Most probably you were confused between "for" and "do-while" loops, that happens. I too, when I was a beginner, used to be confused of such things.